# Given a tridiagonal, 10x10 matrix, how can I show that its largest eigenvalue is greater than 1?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

EDIT: I have finished this problem -- if anyone has interest in solving this problem, too, please read up on Rayleigh Quotients, the Courant min-max principle, and the interlacing property that the two theorems imply -- in this order.  Have fun :-)

Given a tri-diagonal, $10x10$ matrix A, I want to show that

a) its largest eigenvalue $\lambda_{max}(A)>1$

b) the matrix has 9 negative eigenvalues

the matrix is

$$\left(\begin{matrix}1&-3&0&0&\cdots&0&0\\-3&-2&1&0&\cdots&0&0\\0&1&-2&1&\cdots&0&0\\0&0&1&-2&\cdots&0&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\0&0&0&0&\cdots&-2&1\\0&0&0&0&\cdots&1&-2\end{matrix}\right)_{10\times10}$$

How can I get started on this problem?  What concepts are being tested here?  This is an old linear algebra exam question, dating back to 1994 :-)

Thanks,

Comment: yes, absolutely, @Element118  :-)

Comment: The largest  eigenvalue of the leading principal $2\times 2$ submatrix is larger than one, so the largest eigenvalues of the whole matrix is so as well due to the interlacing property.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Cauchy_interlacing_theorem

Comment: By considering the trailing principal $9\times9$ submatrix, you may also prove part (b) using the interlacing property.

Comment: Hi @user1551 - I did just exactly what you said last night, but admittedly not without a peak at the solution.  The Courant min-max principle, Rayleigh quotients, and the interlacing property that the two theorems imply, are pretty new to me, but it turned out to be not so bad to pick up -- and very useful to learn.  Thanks for your comment.  Have a great night :-)

Comment: Can you post the solution? I am intrested enough to read it but not enough to tackle it myself.